# UIViewController default transition animation not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a `viewController` modally in a `navigationController` and then push another view after `x-seconds` , but for some reason, the `first` and the `second view` are presented without animation. I tried to `dispatch UI` related code on the main thread but it didn't fix the bug.

I use `navigationController.setViewControllers([vc]), animated: true)`
 first and then `rootViewController.present(navigationController, animated: true)`, for both views,

Any idea why animations are missing?

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
Self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

When `present modally`, you should you `presentViewController` method.
When `push` into `navigationController`, you should use `pushViewController`.
If you want to `present` first, say `VC1` present `NC2`(have VC2 as root). Then you should use `NC2` to `pushViewController`.